Controling Android TV via Android phone like a tablet
I'm looking for an Android app that is able to show me the screen of Android TV v12 on my Android phone v7.1 and of course this shown screen needs to be interactive, e.g. I would need to control the smart TV with the phone.

Please note that this is opposite of standard screen casting, e.g. cast phone screen on TV.
And this is also different from turning the phone screen into TV remote.
And also different from projecting the TV screen to the phone.

I did some searching, but I couldn't find anything working, even if those found apps (EShare, AirDroid, AnyDesk, TeamViewer, ScreenMirror, GoogleHome, and 50! more) claimed to support this functionality.
The reason to turn Smart TV into tablet via phone is to manage sideloaded apps that have no TV support as they can't be fully controlled by a standard or virtual remote.
